# Code to step through an array and output the text

Tags: node.js, loops

I'm working on a function within a nodejs project to output the contents of an array, one element at a time.  The contents will be output to a Facebook messenger window, but there will be a time delay between outputs to allow the user time to read each phrase.

The output is supposed to function as follows:

```
IF it is the first element
    Get element text
    Calculate delay based on word count
    Send text (no delay for first element)
ELSE
    Get next element
    Send text with delay
    Calculate delay for next element
REPEAT UNTIL ALL ELEMENTS SENT
```

The code for this operation looks like this:

```
sendMultipartMessage: function(recipientID, textArray)
{
    let msgLength = textArray.length;
    let msgDelay, msgPartCount = 0, msgTextPart;
    while (msgPartCount < msgLength)
    {
        if (msgPartCount === 0)
        {
            msgTextPart = textArray[msgPartCount];  // Get the first part of the message
            msgDelay = common.calculateDelay(msgTextPart);
            console.log("Working with message part %s", (msgPartCount+1));
            self.sendTextMessage(recipientID, msgTextPart);
        }
        else
        {
            msgTextPart = textArray[msgPartCount];  // Get the next part of the message
            console.log("Working with message part %s", (msgPartCount+1));
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                self.sendTextMessage(recipientID, msgTextPart);
            }, msgDelay);
            msgDelay = common.calculateDelay(msgTextPart);  // Delay sending the next part to give user time to read the previous part
        }
        msgPartCount++;
    }
},
```

When I run the code it only outputs the following:

```
MESSAGE    PART    1
MESSAGE    PART    4
MESSAGE    PART    4
MESSAGE    PART    4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to StackOverflow user [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills) for helping to get this working - see my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659434/trying-to-write-a-function-to-use-callbacks-to-send-a-facebook-messenger-message)!

My eventual solution for this looked like this:

```
sendMultiPartMessage: function(recipientId, textArray) {
    let index = 0, msgPart, msgData;
    const sendMessagePart = function(textArray, index) {
        msgPart = textArray[index];
        msgData = {
            recipient: {
                id: recipientId
            },
            message: {
                text: msgPart
            }
        };
        self.sendCallbackMessage(msgData, function(sent) {
            index++;
            if (sent && (index < textArray.length)) {
                sendMessagePart(textArray, index);
            }
        });
    };
    sendMessagePart(textArray, index);
},

sendCallbackMessage: function(messageData, callback) {
    request({
            uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
            qs: {
                access_token: config.FB_PAGE_TOKEN
            },
            method: 'POST',
            json: messageData

        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                let recipientId = body.recipient_id;
                console.log("Message sent to recipient '%s'", recipientId);
                callback(true);
            } else {
                console.error("Could not send message: ", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To start: my apologies if there are some mistakes in this post, this is my first post on a stack.

It looks like your loop has finished looping over all the elements before the second send could be executed. I would suggest that you use promises or the async library. That way you can enforce that the while loop waits for previous iterations.

sample for async:

```
var async = require('async'); // don't forget to npm install the async library 
/*
...
*/
sendMultipartMessage: function(recipientID, textArray){

    let msgDelay = 0, msgPartCount = 0;
    async.each(textArray, function(msgTextPart, callback){

    console.log("Working with message part %s", (msgPartCount+1));
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.sendTextMessage(recipientID, msgTextPart);
        }, msgDelay);
        msgDelay = common.calculateDelay(msgTextPart);
        callback();

    }, function(error){} // final callback that contains error if something went wrong )
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How would you suggest rewriting this code to use callbacks?  I have never used async and I don't plan on doing so.

Comment: If you do not want to use async I suggest you look up on how to use promises. It will get the job done just like async would but I havn't much experience with it.

Comment: I have no experience of promises either.  I have looked at how to use them and they are too confusing.  I was hoping I could use callbacks.  Thanks anyway.